# How to add SLD to a wms layer dynamically from javascript

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript

How to add SLD style which is written in String format  and stored in a 'var' variable of javascript and asign it to a WMS layer while creating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the styles parameter with an SLD parameter that contains your style. The following code from [this example](http://gis.ibbeck.de/OLClient/examples/wms_sld_world.asp) demonstrates the concept.

```
            theSLD_BODY= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + '<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengeospatial.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"><NamedLayer><Name>COUNTRY</Name><UserStyle><FeatureTypeStyle><Rule><ogc:Filter><ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escape="!"><ogc:PropertyName>Continent</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>Africa</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsLike></ogc:Filter><PolygonSymbolizer><Fill><CssParameter name="fill">#5599DD</CssParameter></Fill><Stroke><CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter></Stroke></PolygonSymbolizer></Rule></FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></NamedLayer></StyledLayerDescriptor>';
        layer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Africa (SLD_BODY)",
                "http://gis.ibbeck.de/include/mapserver/mapserv.exe?map=/daten/mapfiles/world/World.map",
                {   "layers": "COUNTRY",
                    "format": "image/png",
                    "version": "1.1.1",
                    "transparent": "TRUE",
                    "SLD_BODY": theSLD_BODY
                });
```

You may encounter problems if the SLD becomes too long as it may exceed the maximum URL length of your browser. In which case you will need to switch to POST instead of GET requests.