# Styling WMS layer using SLD in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, sld

I want to style WMS layer using SLD in OpenLayers 3. written part of code shown below.  There are not any console error messages shown but no styles are applied to the layer...

```
var sld = '<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0">';
                sld+= '<NamedLayer>';
                sld+= '<Name>topp:tasmania_roads</Name>';
                sld+= '<UserStyle>';
                sld+= '<IsDefault>1</IsDefault>';
                sld+= '<FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '<Rule>';
                sld+= '<LineSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<Stroke>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="stroke">';
                sld+= '<Literal>#787878</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="stroke-width">';
                sld+= '<Literal>2</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '</Stroke>';
                sld+= '</LineSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '</Rule>';
                sld+= '</FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '</UserStyle>';
                sld+= '</NamedLayer>';

                sld+= '<NamedLayer>';
                sld+= '<Name>topp:tasmania_water_bodies</Name>';
                sld+= '<UserStyle>';
                sld+= '<IsDefault>1</IsDefault>';
                sld+= '<FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '<Rule>';
                sld+= '<LineSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<Stroke>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="stroke">';
                sld+= '<Literal>#4F94CD</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="stroke-width">';
                sld+= '<Literal>3</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '</Stroke>';
                sld+= '</LineSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<PolygonSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<Fill>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="fill">';
                sld+= '<Literal>#63B8FF</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '</Fill>';
                sld+= '</PolygonSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '</Rule>';
                sld+= '</FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '</UserStyle>';
                sld+= '</NamedLayer>';

                sld+= '<NamedLayer>';
                sld+= '<Name>topp:tasmania_cities</Name>';
                sld+= '<UserStyle>';
                sld+= '<IsDefault>1</IsDefault>';
                sld+= '<FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '<Rule>';
                sld+= '<PointSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<Graphic>';
                sld+= '<Mark>';
                sld+= '<WellKnownName>cross</WellKnownName>';
                sld+= '<Fill>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="fill">';
                sld+= '<Literal>#00FF00</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '</Fill>';
                sld+= '</Mark>';
                sld+= '<Size>15</Size>';
                sld+= '</Graphic>';
                sld+= '</PointSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<TextSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<Label><PropertyName>CITY_NAME</PropertyName></Label>';
                sld+= '<Font>';
                sld+= '<SvgParameter name="font-size">15</SvgParameter>';
                sld+= '</Font>';
                sld+= '</TextSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '</Rule>';
                sld+= '</FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '</UserStyle>';
                sld+= '</NamedLayer>';

                sld+= '<NamedLayer>';
                sld+= '<Name>topp:tasmania_state_boundaries</Name>';
                sld+= '<UserStyle>';
                sld+= '<IsDefault>1</IsDefault>';
                sld+= '<FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '<Rule>';
                sld+= '<PolygonSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '<Fill>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="fill">';
                sld+= '<Literal>#8B8989</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="fill-opacity">';
                sld+= '<Literal>0.2</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '</Fill>';
                sld+= '<Stroke>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="stroke">';
                sld+= '<Literal>#FF4040</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '<CssParameter name="stroke-width">';
                sld+= '<Literal>2</Literal>';
                sld+= '</CssParameter>';
                sld+= '</Stroke>';
                sld+= '</PolygonSymbolizer>';
                sld+= '</Rule>';
                sld+= '</FeatureTypeStyle>';
                sld+= '</UserStyle>';
                sld+= '</NamedLayer>';

                sld+= '</StyledLayerDescriptor>';

var wms = new ol.layer.Tile(
    {
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({title: "Population Density",url: 'http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms',params: {LAYERS: 'gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000',STYLES: undefined,SLD_BODY: sld}}),
        style: styles,


    });
```

Comment: Does this help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124173/openlayers-3-submit-sld-text-in-wms-call

Comment: What request is sent? Do you get any errors?