# Set a new SLD style in openlayers 3 for WMS request

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2

I im triyng to submit a SLD style in openlayers 3 to change the color of my WMS(geoserver) But nothing is working...Anybody have a idea?

Here is my code:

```
   var wms_p_popf = new ol.layer.Tile({
        name: 'wms_p_popf',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DatashinePBS/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS':'DatashinePBS:PopF'},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        }),
        maxResolution: 850

        });
        wms_p_popf.updateParams({STYLES: undefined, SLD_BODY: SLD});

var SLD = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
        '<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">'+
         '<NamedLayer>'+
            '<se:Name>pack_geomarketing_iris13_region</se:Name>'+
            '<UserStyle>'+
             '<se:Name>pack_geomarketing_iris13_region</se:Name>'+
             '<se:FeatureTypeStyle>'+
                '<se:Rule>'+
                 '<se:Name>0.0000 - 20.9136</se:Name>'+
                 '<se:Description>'+
                    '<se:Title>0.0000 - 20.9136</se:Title>'+
                 '</se:Description>'+
                 '<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">'+
                    '<ogc:And>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>20.9136</ogc:Literal>'+
                    '</ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                  '</ogc:And>'+
                 '</ogc:Filter>'+
                 '<se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                    '<se:Fill>'+
                     '<se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f1eef6</se:SvgParameter>'+
                    '</se:Fill>'+
                 '</se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                '</se:Rule>'+
                '<se:Rule>'+
                 '<se:Name>20.9136 - 46.5812</se:Name>'+
                 '<se:Description>'+
                    '<se:Title>20.9136 - 46.5812</se:Title>'+
                '</se:Description>'+
                 '<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">'+
                    '<ogc:And>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>20.9136</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>46.5812</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                    '</ogc:And>'+
                 '</ogc:Filter>'+
                '<se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                    '<se:Fill>'+
                     '<se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d7b5d8</se:SvgParameter>'+
                    '</se:Fill>'+
                 '</se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                '</se:Rule>'+
                '<se:Rule>'+
                 '<se:Name>46.5812 - 50.4112</se:Name>'+
                 '<se:Description>'+
                  '<se:Title>46.5812 - 50.4112</se:Title>'+
                 '</se:Description>'+
                 '<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">'+
                    '<ogc:And>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>46.5812</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>50.4112</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                    '</ogc:And>'+
                 '</ogc:Filter>'+
                 '<se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                    '<se:Fill>'+
                     '<se:SvgParameter name="fill">#df65b0</se:SvgParameter>'+
                    '</se:Fill>'+
                 '</se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                '</se:Rule>'+
                '<se:Rule>'+
                 '<se:Name>50.4112 - 53.8128</se:Name>'+
                 '<se:Description>'+
                    '<se:Title>50.4112 - 53.8128</se:Title>'+
                 '</se:Description>'+
                 '<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">'+
                    '<ogc:And>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>50.4112</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>53.8128</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                    '</ogc:And>'+
                '</ogc:Filter>'+
                '<se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                    '<se:Fill>'+
                     '<se:SvgParameter name="fill">#dd1c77</se:SvgParameter>'+
                    '</se:Fill>'+
                 '</se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                '</se:Rule>'+
                '<se:Rule>'+
                 '<se:Name>53.8128 - 100.0000</se:Name>'+
                 '<se:Description>'+
                    '<se:Title>53.8128 - 100.0000</se:Title>'+
                 '</se:Description>'+
                 '<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">'+
                    '<ogc:And>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                        '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>53.8128</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>'+
                     '<ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                      '<ogc:PropertyName>p_popf</ogc:PropertyName>'+
                        '<ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>'+
                     '</ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>'+
                    '</ogc:And>'+
                 '</ogc:Filter>'+
                 '<se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                    '<se:Fill>'+
                     '<se:SvgParameter name="fill">#980043</se:SvgParameter>'+
                    '</se:Fill>'+
                 '</se:PolygonSymbolizer>'+
                '</se:Rule>'+
             '</se:FeatureTypeStyle>'+
            '</UserStyle>'+
         '</NamedLayer>'+
        '</StyledLayerDescriptor>';


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124173/openlayers-3-submit-sld-text-in-wms-call

Comment: I try te solution of this post but i dont know why it not working... My code use the solution of this post

Comment: then show us some code

Comment: I edit the code

Comment: if you need more info tell me :)

Answer (score 1):

For a remote SLD to be applied to a Layer you must make sure that the `<Name>` in the `<NamedLayer>` is the same as the name of the layer you are styling.

So in your case `pack_geomarketing_iris13_region` doesn't match `DatashinePBS:PopF` so nothing is drawn.

You might also want to check in GeoServer that the SLD is in fact valid (as GeoServer doesn't implement the whole of the Style Encoding SE spec that you seem to be using).

Comment: My layer is working with the SLD i submit in Geosever and my object are correctly display in openlayers. Now the problem is that i want to change the SLD by default in geoserver by a SLD i put in openlayer.
I jus try to submit the SLD that i want to put in openalyer to modify the WMS in geoserver and i work...so i dont think it the name layer problem

Comment: The named layer problem only occurs in remote SLDs

Comment: the style work in geoserver so i dont think it the named layer...

Comment: i got a new error in chrome net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

You have updated params before you'd defined the SLD variable.

```
wms_p_popf.updateParams({STYLES: undefined, SLD_BODY: SLD});
var SLD = ...
```

Comment: i put it before just here, but in my computer is after