# Adding SLD using OpenLayers 3

Tags: wms, sld, openlayers

I wonder if I can add SLD style to WMS or WFS layer existing in GeoServer, using OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add SLD style to WMS request, while WFS requsts can be styled with [ol.style](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.html).

Example of Openlayers WMS request below. You can use either existing SLD on a given url or add SLD string to sld body. With long styles you will probably need to use [POST method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175057/openlayers-3-wms-styling-using-sld-body-and-post-request).

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    'z-index': 1,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: url,
        projection: wmsProjection,
        preload: Infinity,
        params: {
            "VERSION": wmsVersion,
            "LAYERS": layerName,
            "TILED": true,
            "SLD": sldUrl,
            /*"SLD_BODY": sldBody*/
        }
        }),
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    });
```

If you are interested in saving SLD to Geoserver then you will have to get familiar with [Geoserver REST API](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Well it is certainly possible to construct an SLD and send it directly or by reference as part of a WMS GetMap request to a GeoServer service, with OpenLayers as a client.  This is something done by the OneGeology portal as part of their thematic analysis tools.

It isn't possible for WFS, because a WFS doesn't deal in styling, you just get the raw data from the server and have to render it in your client.