# Dynamic filter on tile (WMS) layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, filter

I have a tile layer with a WMS source coming from GeoServer. I want to add and change a filter to it when a user changes their selection. I can see some examples for OpenLayers 3 and Vector layers but the OpenLayers.Filter class has changed and I can't get it to have any effect.

```
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OlOr from 'ol/format/filter/Or';
import OlEq from 'ol/format/filter/EqualTo';



this.structureLayer = new OlTileLayer({
  source: new TileWMS({
    url: 'http://test.com/fpat/wms', 
    params: {'LAYERS': 'fpat:fpat_surveys',
              'TILED': true},
    serverType: 'geoserver',
    transition: 0
  })
});


 this.structureLayer.filter = new OlOr(new OlEq('structure_types', 'Natural') , new OlEq('structure_types', 'Other'));
```

When the user changes their selection I'll need to rebuild the filter and make sure the layer updates. The [documentation for a vector layer with a spatial filter](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-spatial-filter.js) suggests this, but I I get an error because `refresh` doesn't exist

```
this.structureLayer.refresh({force: true})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to refresh the params of the source of `structureLayer`. Don't try to use OpenLayers 2 syntax thinking it would work by luck on OpenLayers 3+: OpenLayers 3+ is a full rewrite (remark comes from your attempt to use `this.structureLayer.refresh({force: true})`)

It should be more

```
// Get existing parameters collection
var params = this.structureLayer.getSource().getParams();
// I choose to use CQL_FILTER instead of sld
params.CQL_FILTER = "structure_types IN ('Natural', 'Other')";
// Uncomment line below and comment line above if you prefer using sld
// params.sld_body = "yourxmlfiltercontent"; 
this.structureLayer.getSource().updateParams(params);
```

You can use filter but you will need to create your own XML as the ol.format.filter are intended for WFS not WMS. That's why I've use `cql_filter` instead above (it does the same job with a more simple syntax)

You can see [a demo to show "it works"](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/debc42e960a0d3df17ccf0600d8a49bd)

You should also consider using POST (default behaviour using GET and there are restrictions on length of HTTP GET call Url). You may need to look at this related post [OpenLayers 3 WMS Styling Using SLD_BODY and POST request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175057/openlayers-3-wms-styling-using-sld-body-and-post-request)

PS: I'm using the "OpenLayers pre-ES6" syntax in the demo but the logic remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for that will try asap. Since the number of options the user can turn on may make a cql filter too long for a URL I might go for the XML filter. I can write it manually but I don't know how to apply that to a layer in OL. Could you add that to your answer?